# How to make my macro won't be disturbed by content assistance?

Tags: macros, intellij-idea

I have defined a macro in my Intellij-IDEA, which is a combination of:

1. go to line end
2. type <kbd>{</kbd>
3. press <kbd>enter</kbd>

This is the configuration (append_brace_enter):

[image: idea macro conf]

This is a little example show it works, the `|` means cursor:

```
if(true | )
```

Then press the keyshort for my macro, it will become:

```
if(true ) {
   |
}
```

Most of time it works fine but sometimes, when I press the keyshort and there is a content assistance list, it won't work as I expect. I have to press <kbd>esc</kbd> to hide the list, but which waste me of nearly 1 second.

Here is a screencast to show the problem:

[image: idea macro problem]

You can see when I type `if(a>b)` and invoke the macro, it will become an `AutoCloseable {}`, which is not what I want.

Is there any solution to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Complete Statement (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) for that.
You can also add <kbd>Esc</kbd> to your macro.
You can change Settings | Editor | Code Completion | Preselect the first suggestion to Never, End will go to the line end then.
In [12.1 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12.1+EAP) the default behaviour also doesn't get so much in the way.

Comment: I can't add `Esc` to the macro, because it will cause strange behavior: the idea will hide to minimal.

Comment: I just found I can use <kbd>right</kbd> and <kbd>left</kbd> before <kbd>end</kbd>, it works but I don't think it's a good solution. I hope there is some configuration for macro to disable content assistance.